# How to select n random keys from a `StorageMap`?

Tags: storage, map, random, iteration

Assume I have the following storage map:

`ZAccounts: StorageMap(AccountId -> AccountInfoOf<T>)`

Is there a simple way to draw `n` AccountId's randomly. I assume that I already have a secure random source (BABE or VRF).

I mean if I use `let accounts: Vec<_> = ZAccounts::<T>::iter().collect();` (to select a random subset later) I have the flaw of an unbounded vector. And additionally I have a storage read for every iteration (pretty expensive).

Then there is the possibility to have a `BoundedVec`. That would be easy, but I have the constraint that there is no limit (unbounded).

So maybe you know a possibility to know beforehand the key to query for a storage map based on internal storage structure with [hasher](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/trait.StorageHasher.html).

Can I somehow calculate a key from storage and then map some index to it. Then I could map an index to a storage key. Like for example:

`StorageMap(u128 -> AccountId)`

It could be done like that, but what if one (index -> AccountId) is deleted. Then there are missing indices. At the end this leads to a list of active indices again (like [0, 2, 3, 4 ...] where 1 got removed for some dynamic use-case in which an AccountId should be deleted).

On Zeitgeist a court system needs to get implemented. This requires to select n random jurors from an unbounded list of possible jurors. What would you propose?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a `StorageValue<Vec<(Index, AccountId)>>`.

```rs
let v = StorageValue::get();
let index = v[random % v.len()];
let account_id = v[i];
```

---

Or `StorageMap<Index, AccountId>` + `StorageValue<Count>`.

```rs
let count = StorageValue::get();
let index = random % count;
let account_id = StorageMap::get(index);
```

Note you must not delete the middle item in this map(actually, it looks like a link list structure). You should use swap and delete the item from the tail (also, update the counter correctly).

Comment: Good thought. I would like to have an unlimited number of AccountId's. So there should be for example a million and more juror account ids.

Comment: How many elements in this vector could be possible? I mean there is some weight limitation with this operation, right? As soon as I access the content of the `StorageValue` I need to decode a large vector.

Comment: How about my second option?

Comment: That's better. The interesting part is to swap and deleting the element from the tail. I mean at the moment when removing from the middle all indices need to shift (minus one for following elements).

Comment: You shouldn't remove it. You need to use a new account to swap the account you want to remove.

Comment: Anyway, the question is how to build a relationship between `u128` and `AccountId`. LOL

Comment: I see, but what if I don't have an account in place for that. So assume our list contains 100 elements of accounts. Now one account decides to get removed (in the middle of all indices). (This should be allowed for a juror in a court.)

Comment: You might need another storage to cache the empty slot... And what about letting users or offchain worker provide the `u128 -> AccountId`.(Just a immature ideas)

Comment: Caching empty slots is really intelligent. Let me think about this... Off chain worker is interesting too, but always as I used this path I run into trouble of centralised parts.

Comment: When I hit an empty slot with my random number then I could just use an existing index to the left. But this increases the probability for certain indices which are surrounded by many empty slots...